# Meteor JS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, driver, meteor

Is there a simple way for Meteor.js to interact with a SQL Server the same way it does with MongoDB? For example, by using the Node.js MSSQL driver found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995 - however ideally this needs to work in linux.

The closest I have found was [tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) - how can I use this, or another alternative, in Meteor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably have read the meteor docs. You will find it is given [there](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity) :

> The current release of Meteor supports MongoDB, the popular document
>   database, and the examples in this section use the MongoDB API. Future
>   releases will include support for other databases.

So until 'that' future release, you won't have native support for other databases. Your best shot is to use packages that allow you to connect MS-SQL. You can check the packages listed [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mssql) or search them [here](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/mssql). Some of them are:

1. https://npmjs.org/package/tedious
2. https://npmjs.org/package/msnodesql
3. https://npmjs.org/package/tds

Better use one that is popular and more recently updated.

Comment: I mentioned the driver & tedious in my original question - tds has been defunct for over a year now. Have you got any examples of using the MSSQL driver for Node within Meteor, or tedious?

Comment: I found this example http://shiggyenterprises.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/accessing-an-mssql-database-from-meteor/. It is in coffeescript, so copy the raw code and then use http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/ 'Try CoffeeScript' to get JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately `__meteor_bootstrap.require` doesn't work outside of `isServer`. However it's been replaced in 0.6 by `Npm.require`. Unfortunately for me 0.6 is only available on *nix & mac distro.