# Can we use Meteor framework with mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, meteor

I found many refer url for Meteor framework where i found mongodb as database, since i don't have much knowledge in mongodb. So is there any way to implement mysql instead of mongodb

Comment: I've built a MySQL package on behalf of a client. They would like to release it as open source, so stay tuned. It started as fixing showstopper issues in Dror's version and it wasn't long before I realized I needed to rewrite it completely for production use.

Comment: @matb33 i am looking forward to your updates

Comment: Refer to the answer on this page. [meteor-js-and-sql-server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879752/meteor-js-and-sql-server#answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There *is* a way, but at the stage the framework is right now it's an unpaved road. Basically, you'd need to write a wrapper that would translate from SQL to Meteor's Minimongo and back. It's not a feasible task if you're not a Meteor and Mongo master already.

There were attempts to write such adapter. The most advanced I know is this: https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql . It's possible to use to play around, but I don't think it's production ready. Also, there is currently **no** way to use Meteor account system with anything other than Mongo. You either need to use it anyway for user accounts, or give up a great convenience they provide.

I'd advice you to try Meteor as it currently is, together with Mongo - it's easier than you think. It doesn't add too much learning curve, and besides filter and update operators you won't notice that you use some strange db at all - it's just like working with native Javascript objects. There's no schema, no migrations, no object mapping needed. You just take data, put it in a collection and forget all the rest that SQL made you think about.

Comment: Regarding the timeline for official SQL support, Geoff Schmidt (Meteor co-founder) says that will come after Meteor 1.0: 
http://youtu.be/ixt5MQBA5f8?t=11m45s
http://youtu.be/ixt5MQBA5f8?t=22m10s

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/):

> Today most Meteor apps use MongoDB as their database because it is the
>   best supported, though support for other databases is coming in the
>   future. The Meteor.Collection class is used to declare Mongo
>   collections and to manipulate them. Thanks to minimongo, Meteor's
>   client-side Mongo emulator, Meteor.Collection can be used from both
>   client and server code.

As the client side uses minimongo, using a RDBMS may not provide the best fit (as the query language and data structures are very different).

You might be interested in something like [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/) which comes at the problem of rich data synchronization services from a different direction, but it fits relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a way to do that but it's tricky :

Install a Mysql driver from npm
Then You can choose to use MongoDb as a first front-end or Meteor Streams from Arunoda.
Then You just have to use the deny/allow system from Meteor.Collections to bind insert/update/remove from client side to Mysql
You should also use the publish system to query Mysql database and return data to the client.

The last problem is about server database observing : if something change in Mysql, it won't alert all other client, except maybe with Meteor.Streams.
That could be rather fun to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this meteor package [nodets:mysql](https://atmospherejs.com/nodets/mysql) .
Use mysql at the server and at the client all subscriptions are updated every time db changes.