# How to access mysql db from meteor

Tags: mysql, meteor

Is there a way to import data from MySQL database on Meteor startup? I basically need just an initial data from MySQL to export it to Mongo collections for usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269075/can-we-use-meteor-framework-with-mysql-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet might be to just use a mysql node package (remember to use `Meteor.npmRequire(..)` instead of `require(..)`). This one seems good:

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Something like this should work:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var mysql = Meteor.npmRequire('mysql');
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'me',
            password : 'secret'
        });

        connection.connect();

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // create documents from rows[i] and add to your collection
        });

        connection.end();

    });
}
```